# store username in keychain with different key

Tags: ios, objective-c, keychain

I want to store username and password in keychain.  As far I have explored we can store it and retrieve it like this

**Store username and password**

```
[_keychainObject setObject:username forKey:(id)kSecAttrAccount];
[_keychainObject setObject:password forKey:(id)kSecValueData];
```

**Retrieve username and password**

```
NSLog(@"%@", [_keychainObject objectForKey:(id)kSecAttrAccount]);
NSLog(@"%@", [_keychainObject objectForKey:(id)kSecValueData]);
```

Why can't we store it like this

```
[_keychainObject setObject:username forKey:@"username"];
```

If I do so its not storing the data.  Is it mandatory to use predefined keys to store an item in keychain?

Answer (score 0):

For Objective-C try

https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/UICKeyChainStore

for Swift try

https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/KeychainAccess

```
var keychain = Keychain()
keychain["username"] = "abc" // Set string
var userName = keychain["username"] // Get string
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend checking out SAMKeychain https://github.com/soffes/SAMKeychain.